# Breakeven for Excel

Tags: excel

I would like an excel formula for the below.  For each month (columns) I have a total (all in same row).  I want to sum the range of totals and highlight the month in which the cumulative sum of months turns positive.  These totals will change based on other variables.

Columns = A1 through L1 (months)
Totals in row B for each month

Comment: Need to see what your table looks like.  But this is not a difficult formula by any means.

Comment: A1 January, B1 February, C1 March; A2 -10, B2 -5, C2 20.  The answer would sum A2:C2 and then highlight C1 (this is when the sum turns positive and which respective month this happens in)

Comment: You would use conditional formatting with the following formula:  `=SUM($A$2:A$2)>0`

Comment: OK Scott Craner - what if I want to exclude a cell in the range e.g., a subtotal?  I want a cumulative sum of 12 months, then the next 12 months, then the next 12 months while ignoring the column with the total which would be the 13 column in the first set, the 26 column in the second set, etc. while still maintaining the formatting that highlights when the sum of the range turns positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your cumulative total will be in row 3, in `A3` you would put the formula:

```
=SUM($A$2:A2)
```

note the dollar signs in the first part of the range. When you now copy it down the row the second part will change creating a cumulative sum of the total values.

To highlight the first positive value you would select the whole range of cumulative values (say `A3:X3`) and create New Rule for conditional formatting, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", and place the following formula as the condition:

```
=A3=MIN(IF($A$3:$X$3>0,$A$3:$X$3,""))
```

Which will highlight the lowest non negative value in your row with the formatting you select. Hope this helps. Regards,

Comment: Tested it and it worked without the array formula. Cheers,